# Find linearized equation at equilibrium

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, linearization

The differential equation below has an equilibrium at $x=1$:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = (e^{x}-1)(x-1)$

The problem asks to find the linearized equation but in terms of $h$, where $h=x-a$.

$\frac{dh}{dt}=f'(a)h$

The correct answer is $(e-1)h$, but I don't see how to get there.

I've tried first replacing $x$ in the original equation with $h+a$, simplifying, and then working with series. But I don't arrive at the above answer.

What are some approaches to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the derivative of the right hand side at $x=1$:
$$
f'(x)=e^x(x-1)+e^x-1
$$
So,
$$
f'(1)=e-1
$$
and your linearized equation is the one you have.